# How to subgroup in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx, graph-theory

I have dirty grouped lists of Ids **ids_group_dirty** and I need to regroup it to get following results:

{dirty_grp_0: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  (ids 1,2,3 comes together and id 4 grouped with 3 and 5 grouped with 4).
{dirty_grp_3: 6} (id 6 comes along).

I've already broken my brain :)
Anyone can solve this puzzle ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ids_group_dirty = {
    'dirty_grp_0': [1, 2, 3],
    'dirty_grp_1': [3, 4],
    'dirty_grp_2': [4, 5],
    'dirty_grp_3': [6]
}

unique_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(ids_group_dirty.values())))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ids_group_dirty.keys(), columns=unique_ids)

for grp in ids_group_dirty.keys():
    df.loc[grp] = np.where(df.columns.isin(ids_group_dirty[grp]), 1.0, np.nan)


df
               1    2    3    4    5    6
dirty_grp_0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
dirty_grp_1  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
dirty_grp_2  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
dirty_grp_3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: Is pandas mandatory here (school project, ...) ? Moreover, I don't get your desired output, why should it be a dictionary and why 6 should be linked to the key 3 ? If you can clarified your post, I will gladly help you

Comment: @Zelemist, hi! Pandas not mandatory here, but I'm looking for best performance. Code running on PyPy, so Numba can't be used and **ids_group_dirty** dict contains more then 500000 groups with ~100000 ids each. I've edited posts and converted lists to dict. Please let me know if you can understand task now.

Comment: you should not use where, concatenate then. These are pretty slow operations, and pandas seems not the best fit here, using a graph approach will be more helpful. Moreover, we didn't answer regarding the key desired for 6

Comment: @Zelemist, id: 6 comes along with dirty_grp_3. And it's a single ID without any relations to any other groups.

Answer (score 1):

I think dict comprehension would be the fastest. Here we are essentially creating record for each key in `ids_group_dirty`

```
pd.DataFrame({k: {i: 1 for i in v} for k, v in ids_group_dirty.items()}).T
```

---

```
               1    2    3    4    5    6
dirty_grp_0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
dirty_grp_1  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
dirty_grp_2  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
dirty_grp_3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a graph problem, which you can solve with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import pairwise 
# pairwise is python ≥3.10
# or use pairwise recipe:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise


G = nx.Graph()
for l in ids_group_dirty.values():
    if len(l)<2:
        G.add_nodes_from(l)
    for i in l:
        G.add_edges_from(pairwise(l))

groups = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

output: `[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6}]`

graph:

[image]

Comment: it's great! however I'm limited to embedded python modules and pandas/numpy.... :( any idea how to implement the same avoiding **networkx** ?